# How to send transactional mail with csv/excel attachment in magento 2

Tags: magento2, attachment

How can i send transactional mail with csv/excel attachment in magento 2? below is my code:

```
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\FactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
class UploadTransportBuilder extends TransportBuilder {
    public function __construct(FactoryInterface $templateFactory,
        MessageInterface $message,
        SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory) {
        parent::__construct($templateFactory,
            $message,
            $senderResolver,
            $objectManager,
            $mailTransportFactory);    }
    public function attachFile($file, $name) {
        if (!empty($file) && file_exists($file)) {
            $this->message
            ->createAttachment(
                file_get_contents($file),
                \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                basename($name));
            return true;  }
 return false;
    }
}
```

**and i send mail with attachment**

```
$transportBuilder = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\UploadTransportBuilder');
        $path='D:\asd.csv';
        //end here
        $templateId=1;
        $storeId=1;
        $templateParams['test']='test test';
        $transport =$transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId])
            ->setTemplateVars($templateParams)
            ->setFrom(array('email'=>'anand@gmail.com', 'name'=>'anand'))
            ->addTo('anand.ontigeri@alshaya.com','anand.ontigeri')
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->attachFile($path,'asd');
        $transport->sendMessage();
```

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport\Interceptor::attachFile() in /var/www/magento2/html/magento2ee/script/Email.php on line 34

Comment: Hi I am also facing same issue ,If you got the solution so can you please share with me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$transport =$transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId])
            ->setTemplateVars($templateParams)
            ->setFrom(array('email'=>'anand@gmail.com', 'name'=>'anand'))
            ->addTo('anand.ontigeri@alshaya.com','anand.ontigeri')
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->attachFile($path,'asd');
        $transport->sendMessage();
```

with

```
$transport =$transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId])
            ->setTemplateVars($templateParams)
            ->setFrom(array('email'=>'anand@gmail.com', 'name'=>'anand'))
            ->addTo('anand.ontigeri@alshaya.com','anand.ontigeri')
            ->attachFile($path,'asd') //Add attachFile here
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
```